# Cannot find tabbed panel struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I am trying to add tabbed layout to a jsp page using struts2 but the TabbedPanel is not being found. I'm using struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to add <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %> on top of your page?
You should also add the struts-dojo-plugin in your classpath.